# Given the binding, determine what a rails method returns?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to do some processing for every method that runs inside my rails code, for that I require some information about the method during run-time. I am using set_trace_func to do this. Inside set_trace_func we receive binding:

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}
```

How can I determine from this binding what the function will return? I know how to access variables, parameters and the like but can't figure out how to get the return value, also is there a better tool for doing this?

Comment: What function? From where to determine? Please provide an explanation, that is understandable.

Comment: Also, this question has nothing to do with neither rails nor metaprogramming.

Comment: @mudasobwa Does this help?

Comment: No it does not. What function “will return”?

Comment: @mudasobwa I think it explains that set_trace_func "suspends" the function during its execution. So I wanted to know what value it will return, It can be determined by processing the source code or using TracePoint as answered by Stefan below. I would love some more constructive criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set_trace_func` was superseded by [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/TracePoint.html) which is capable of inspecting a method's [`return_value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/TracePoint.html#method-i-return_value):

```
def foo
  2 * 3
end

TracePoint.trace(:return) do |tp|
  puts "`#{tp.method_id}' returned #{tp.return_value.inspect}"
end

foo
```

Output:

```
`foo' returned 6
```

There's also `:c_return` to trace methods implemented in C and `b_return` for blocks.